# Is there a limit of the number of tasks that can be launched by Mesos on a slave?

Tags: task, mesos, slave, marathon

I am currently using Mesos + Marathon for the test.

When I launch a lot of tasks with command `ping 8.8.8.8`, at one point, slaves cannot launch a task any more. So I checked `out stderr` of sandbox, then it shows

> Failed to initialize, pthread_create

I launched tasks with 0.00001 cpus and 0.00001 mems, so enough resources to launch a task remained in slaves.

Is there a limit of the number of tasks that can be launched by Mesos on a slave?

Comment: could there be a limit to the number of icmp requests you can start in parallell? what if you use a different command?

Comment: @JoSSte The issue was same even if I use "while true; do sleep 1; done;" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guees would be you are hitting a [ulimits](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) limit on your slaves. 
Can you try the following:

`#Check max number of threads:
 $ ulimit -u
 1024`

Btw: If you just want to launch dummy tasks I would probably use `sleep 3000` or something like that.

Hope this helps
Joerg

Comment: The result of command "ulimit -u" is 1545932. When that issue was happened, the number of total process was 3074. I can't resolve it yet.